# Can I get the correct type with a large nesting

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I need to get the type as a result of the same as the result2. Is it possible to solve it somehow by changing the function **getNestedProperty**?

```
interface ILevel3 {
  level3: () => void;
}

interface ILevel2 {
  level2: ILevel3;
}
interface ILevel1 {
  level1: ILevel2;
}

const bigNestedObject: ILevel1 = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: () => {}
    }
  }
};

const result = getNestedProperty(bigNestedObject)('level1.level2.level3');
result(); // error type object 

const result2 = bigNestedObject.level1.level2.level3;
result2(); // it's ok type = () => void

const getNestedProperty = (root: object) => (propertyString: string): object => { 
  return propertyString
          .split('.')
          .reduce(<R, KPath extends keyof R>(acc: R, current: KPath): R[KPath] => acc[current], root);
}
```

Can i get in **result** valid type = () => void?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with re-arranging your code. Note that `const getNestedProperty` makes `getNestedProperty` a block-scoped variable. So before using it, you need to declare the variable.

Also note that the final return type from the function, made with higher order function, is of type `object` which lacks he call signature. Thus to call the function object returned, it might be useful to cast it `as` `Function`.

Below is the complete example:

```
//omitting interfaces for brevity

const bigNestedObject: ILevel1 = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: () => {
        console.log("Hello World");
      }
    }
  }
};

function core<R, KPath extends keyof R>(acc: R, current: KPath): any {
  return acc[current];
}

const getNestedProperty = (root: object) => (propertyString: string): object => { 

  //the core function can also be defined here inside getNestedProperty 

  return propertyString
          .split('.')
          //.reduce(<R, KPath extends keyof R>(acc: R, current: KPath): R[KPath] => acc[current], root);

          //the old commented code should also work, 
          //but note this makes the code easier to read.
          .reduce(core, root); 
}

const result = getNestedProperty(bigNestedObject)('level1.level2.level3');
console.log(result); // [Function: level3] 

const result2 = bigNestedObject.level1.level2.level3;
console.log(result2); // [Function: level3]

(result as Function)(); //Hello World
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:** The code above changed and commented ass per suggestion by [Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575107/can-i-get-the-correct-type-with-a-large-nesting/43576008#comment74205964_43576008) below. Note the the new `core` function (find a better name) is added as it makes the code more understandable. The old code, as commented, should also work.

Comment: +1. Can I suggest that you extract the reduce function into a nested function or `const` declaration for readability?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for your suggestion. It will indeed improve readability. But, the code is taken from OP, and I would like to leave it as its present state as that is not causing the problem, and I am not reviewing the code, rather providing a solution for the said problem. Hope you understand.

Comment: @AluanHaddad point taken :) You may like to check the updated answer